# "editor: command not found" when trying to edit Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm learning Rust and can't get the Cargo command working; I'm not sure if it's my mistake or an error.

This is what I typed in the `/src` directory:

```
src [path]$ editor Cargo.toml
```

The reply I got was:

```
-bash: editor: command not found
```

Comment: Do you know the basics of the command line interface and how command shells work? "editor" here is just a placeholder for the actual editor name; the provided command just means that you need to open the file in some editor. Depending on your workflow, it may even be some GUI editor like Sublime Text or Atom.

Comment: I use sublime text 2 on mac, yes i'm learning how command shell works along the way, any suggestions on how i could tackle this ...

Comment: so i use sublime Cargo.toml ... is this what u meant ?

Comment: As Vladimir says above, the command you are having trouble with simply opens the file for editing. You can open this however you want--if you're using sublime it's probably best to open the application first, then navigate to the file using the explorer.

You will need to jump back to the command line to compile (with `cargo build`, or `cargo run`)

Comment: *Why* did you type `editor Cargo.toml`? Did you get these instructions from somewhere? Perhaps the original source could be updated to be more clear, so point us to it.

Comment: Shepmaster http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/hello-cargo.html

Comment: well trying to link subl now using terminal, getting this command "ln: /Users/shaq/bin/subl: No such file or directory"

Comment: thank you Vladmir, bstockwell, and Shepmaster. I managed to link sublime, learned some command shell, used Cargo as well, it was a nice learning experience, Wanted to learn programming, had C++ in mind, then bumped into Rust, so learning from scratch :)

Answer (score 1):

If you literally typed `editor Cargo.toml`, then you're trying to run a program called `editor`, with an argument called `Cargo.toml`. The message you get is the system letting you know that you don't have such a program.

To do what you want to do you can either:

- Write `open -t Cargo.toml` in MacOsX, which opens the file with the system's default text editor (TextEdit, or whatever you may have changed it to).
- Or you can bypass this and open the file directly from your favorite editor's window; the intent here is for you to open and edit the file with any text editor you have installed.

Comment: thanks iajrz, I'm new to terminal commands, and programming ... finally figured out how its done late last night, will have a lot of questions in the future :) any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you found your solution, it'd be nice if you added the answer; if this was the solution, it would be nice if you accepted the answer.

Comment: I switched to atom which was linked and run this $atom Cargo.toml

Answer (score 0):

This means you don't have the editor program installed on your system. Depending on your environment, you might try installing it or using another text editor (say, vim for unix).

Comment: When I try saving the .rs file on sublime the window does not show the folders on my root directory to save it ? trying to google and figure it out, but no luck